# How do I validate that a Cloudwatch Log Group and Log Stream exists?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-java-sdk, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

Is there any method in java to check whether a given Log Group and Log Stream exists, before getting log events from the Log Group?

Answer (score 3):

**Pseudocode: Validate that a log group's log stream exists**

1. Build [describeLogStreamsRequest](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/logs/model/DescribeLogStreamsRequest.html):

   - Pass in your given log group name on the constructor, or on the request's `withLogGroupName` setter.
   - Pass in log stream name in on the request's `withLogStreamNamePrefix` setter.
2. Call [describeLogStreams](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/logs/AWSLogsClient.html#describeLogStreams-com.amazonaws.services.logs.model.DescribeLogStreamsRequest-).
3. Inspect the resulting log streams on the [DescribeLogStreamsResult](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/logs/model/DescribeLogStreamsResult.html) object. If the list isn't empty, you're safe to further operate on that stream.

**Java: Validate that a log group's log stream exists** (*note: untested*)

```
AWSLogsClient logs = new AWSLogsClient();

DescribeLogStreamsRequest req = new DescribeLogStreamsRequest("myLogGroupName")
    .withLogStreamNamePrefix("myLogStreamName");

DescribeLogStreamsResult res = logs.describeLogStreams(req);

if(res != null && res.getLogStreams() != null && !res.getLogStreams().isEmpty())
{
  // Log Stream exists, do work here
}
```

Comment: Just a heads up, a call to `AWSLogsClient#describeLogStreams` with a `logGroupName` that does not exist will generate a `ResourceNotFoundException`. If you are unsure about the existence of the log group, you should handle the exception.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question asks for a Java solution, but this was the top-ranked question on Google when I had the same question for Python. The `boto3` documentation doesn't seem to directly support a "does this log group exist?" function as of today, so here is what I wrote instead. I use the paginator because by default the `boto3` API only lets you pull 50 log groups at a time. The paginator will keep fetching log group names until it goes through all of your log groups.

```
import boto3


def log_group_exists(log_group_name):
    client = boto3.client('logs')
    paginator = client.get_paginator('describe_log_groups')
    for page in paginator.paginate():
        for group in page['logGroups']:
            if group['logGroupName'].lower() == log_group_name.lower():
                return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

In reality, a call to `AWSLogsClient#describeLogStreams` with a `logGroupName` that does not exist will generate a `ResourceNotFoundException`. For that reason, you should check for:

1. Absence of `ResourceNotFoundException`.
2. Existence of a single entry in `DescribeLogStreamsResult#getLogStreams` matching the `logStreamName` provided.

Code snippet of a method that will do that:

```
private boolean doesLogStreamExist() {
    DescribeLogStreamsRequest request = new DescribeLogStreamsRequest()
        .withLogGroupName(logGroupName)
        .withLogStreamNamePrefix(logStreamName);
    try {
        return client.describeLogStreams(request).getLogStreams()
            .stream()
            .anyMatch(it -> it.getLogStreamName().equals(logStreamName));
    } catch (ResourceNotFoundException e) {
        // log group does not exist
        return false;
    }
}
```